# How to fix "ReferenceError: xxx is not defined" for post module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I got an error when trying to append messages (in JSON format) on a page that I've initialized.

This is a code snippet I wrote on *server.js* file, the one that I run "nodemon" to start the server.

```
var messages = [{R1: 0}, {R2: 0}]
app.get('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    res.send( messages )
})

app.post('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    votes.push(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

After I run "nodemon .\server.js", I navigate to http://localhost:8080/votes and I saw the data there.

I want to append more data to that page after getting input from a html page. I have error when executing this code after clicking a button.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
// some logic here
    <script>
        $(() => {
            $("#submit").click(()=>{
                var message = [ { R1: $("#input").val()},
                                { R2: $("#input2").val()}]
                postMessage(message)
            })
        })
        function postMessage(message) {
            $.post('http://localhost:8080/votes', message)
        }
   </script>
</body>
```

It doesn't work, and I have an error in my server console:
**ReferenceError: votes is not defined**

Comment: And, what the error is? What is the `xxx` of `ReferenceError: xxx is not defined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
app.post('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    votes.push(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

`req.body` should be `votes` and you should push it to `res`:

```
app.post('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    res.push(votes)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

`votes` should be defined first

Answer (score 0):

The votes array that is not declared. Try to push to the messages array and not to votes.

```
app.post('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    messages.push(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```